# Couldn't find record without an ID when using foreing_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement a `has_many` `belongs_to` relation with a foreign key.

**Template**

`belongs_to :project`

**Project**

```
has_many :templates
belongs_to :coordinator, foreign_key: :coordinator_id, class_name: 'Person'
```

**Person**

`has_many :projects`

I'm able to do

```
template = Template.new
template.project = Project.new
template.project # my empty project is showed
```

But this doesn't work

```
project = Project.new
project.coordinator = Person.new # Everything is ok until here
project.coordinator # ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Person without an ID
```

I don't know where I'm doing it wrong, maybe I need to specify the primary key in somewhere, but I can't figure it out.

I'm using Rails 4

Comment: Try changing (in Person) `has_many :projects` to `has_many :projects, :as => :coordinator`

Comment: try removing `foreign_key: :coordinator_id` from the `belongs_to` field of project.

Comment: none of those solutions worked.

Answer (score 0):

In Person,

```
has_many :projects, foreign_key: :coordinator_id
```

At the moment it is expecting to find a person_id in the projects table.

Oh, I'd be putting inverse: on the associations too.

Comment: OK -- well it might not fix that specific issue, but you need it in there.